# Using multiple bash variables in another bash command

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to use two variables in another command. For example,

```
var1=$(ls | grep "foo")
var2=$(ls | grep "bar")
common=$(comm -1 -2 <($var1) <($var2))

echo "$common"
```

This is not working. When I write the entire thing in a single line it works.

Edit:
I want to grep two file lists and then print only the common ones. But I still want the variables to be there since they are used in multiple places below.

Comment: Do you have some commands which names contain foo and bar in the current directory?

Comment: Is your sample code in any way representative of something you're actually trying to achieve? I.e. if you were to be offered a better way of comparing file lists, would that be helpful, or do you just want help with `comm`?

Comment: I edited the question to with more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash variables are strings, not lazily evaluated expressions. If you want something which can be evaluated later, use functions.

```
var1() { ls | grep "foo"; }
var2() { ls | grep "bar"; }
common=$(comm -1 -2 <(var1) <(var2))
```

You could refactor that:

```
lsgrep() { ls | grep "$1"; }
common=$(comm -1 -2 <(lsgrep foo) <(lsgrep bar)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as well

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the problems of parsing `ls` and storing commands in variables, you want the actual command, not the result of the command, in your two variables.

```
var1='ls | grep foo'
var2='ls | grep bar'
common=$(comm -1 -2 <($var1) <($var))
```

Let's get rid of the variable first. Use functions to store code.

```
g1 () { ls | grep foo; }
g2 () { ls | grep bar; }

common=$( comm -1 -2 <(g1) <(g2) )
```

Now, let's get rid of `ls`, although this doesn't really solve the actual problem that parsing `ls`'s output presents, which is failure to distinguish a single filename containing a newline from two separate filenames.

```
g1 () { printf '%s\n' *foo*; }
g2 () { printf '%s\n' *bar*; }

common=$( comm -1 -2 <(g1) <(g2) )
```

Comment: The last function just uses file globs of `foo` and `bar` right? So it will just the files having the pattern. But OP wants the filenames containing the pattern `foo`/`bar`?

Comment: True; I created patterns based on the literal examples. In theory, though, you can always replace a regular expression with an *extended* pattern, although the result may be prohibitively large. (`.{2,5}` would be something like `@(??|???|????|?????)`; imagine replacing `.{1,100}`.

Answer (score 1):

`<(cmd)` creates an anonymous file from `cmd`'s *output*. Unless your variables contain commands (which is frowned upon) you should write `<(printf %s "$var")` to create an anonymous file with `$var`'s content.

```
var1=$(ls | grep "foo")
var2=$(ls | grep "bar")
common=$(comm -1 -2 <(printf %s "$var1") <(printf %s "$var2"))
```

Also don't parse the output of `ls`. Use `find` or globbing. In your case, you could replace the whole script with

```
printf '%s\n' * | grep foo | grep bar
```

or even

```
printf '%s\n' *foo*bar* *bar*foo*
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that it's generally accepted that you [shouldn't parse the output ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and you're using bash, I'd recommend using globbing and an array.  Something like this perhaps:

```
$ touch foobar foo_and_bar bar_foo foo_alone just_bar
$ declare -A a b
$ for f in *foo*; do a["$f"]=1; done
$ for f in *bar*; do unset a["$f"]; done
$ declare -p a
declare -A a=([foo_alone]="1" )
```

or

```
$ printf '%q\n' "${!a[@]}"
foo_alone
```

This uses an associative array (which requires bash version 4 or above) to store filenames from the first set as index values. It then steps through the second set, removing files that match, obviously leaving anything that does not match.

The output of this is not a full diff, it's the sort of thing you'd get from `comm -23`, but it handles the comparison natively in bash rather than spawning an external program. You can swap the globs to tune this to make this function like `comm -12`. (But `foo` and `bar` are just placeholders anyway.)

Answer (score -1):

The least modification of the original version goes like this:

```
var1='ls|grep foo'
var2='ls|grep bar'
common=$(comm -1 -2 <(eval $var1) <(eval $var2))
```

The key is to use `eval` and postpone the evaluation of the vars.